# How to force sending data with socket

Tags: c, sockets, buffer

I'm building a Client/Server distributed application via socket in C.
Here is my server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

#define LEN 20

int main(void) {
  int err, nread, status, optval=1;
  int sd, ns;
  char category[LEN];
  struct addrinfo hints, *res;

  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
  hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
  hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

  if((err = getaddrinfo(NULL, "50000", &hints, &res)) != 0) {
    printf("%s", gai_strerror(err));
    exit(-1);
  }

  if((sd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol)) < 0) {
    printf("Error in Socket Server\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof(optval));

  if(bind(sd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) != 0) {
    printf("Error in bind\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  freeaddrinfo(res);

  if(listen(sd, 5) != 0) {
    printf("Error in listen\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  for(;;) {
        if((ns = accept(sd, NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
        printf("Error in accept\n");
        exit(-10);
    }

    /* I tried with this: setsockopt(ns, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char*)&optval, sizeof(int));  
    but it didn't work out */

    while((nread = read(ns, category, LEN)) > 0){

        if(category[nread-1]=='\n') {
            category[nread-1]='\0';
        }

        if(fork()==0) {

        close(1);
        dup(ns);
        close(ns);
        execlp("grep", "grep", category, "conto_corrente.txt", (char *)0);
        perror("Error in fork\n");
        exit(-100);
        }
        wait(&status);
      }

      close(ns);
  }
}
```

And here is my client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
int err, nread;
int sd;
char category[20];
char buff[1024];
struct addrinfo hints, *res, *ptr;

if(argc!=3) {
    printf("Error in number of parameters\n");
    exit(-1);
}

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

if((err = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &res)) != 0) {
    printf("%s\n", gai_strerror(err));
    exit(-1);
}

for(ptr = res; ptr != NULL; ptr=ptr->ai_next) {
    if((sd = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol)) < 0) {continue;}

    if((connect(sd, ptr->ai_addr, ptr->ai_addrlen)) == 0) {
        break;
    }
}

if(ptr==NULL) {
    printf("Error in connection\n");
    exit(-1);
}

freeaddrinfo(res);

printf("Category: ");
scanf("%s", category);

while(strcmp(category, "fine") != 0) {
    write(sd, category, strlen(category)+1);

    while((nread = read(sd, buff, 1024)) > 0) {
        printf("%s", buff);
    }

    printf("Category: ");
    scanf("%s", category);
}
close(sd);

return 0;
}
```

The program should take an input from the user (a string) and send it to the server which have to scan the file and select all the lines that contain that string.

I think there is a problem in the buffering because when the user enter a string then the client stops it looks like it is waiting for something, in fact if I kill the server then the client shows what it read. How is it?

Comment: Get rid of the second read inside the loop.

Comment: Sorry my oversight...but after the first time it is read from the socket then it stops

Comment: The content of 'buff' after the read is printed via 'printf("%.*s", nread, buff);' You are also making the usual mistake of assuming that one write at the send equals one read at the receiver. It ain't so,  it's a byte-stream protocol. You have to loop until you have what you want. Then continue. At present your client is trying to read the socket until end of stream.